# Select from screen - text recognition is gone

Tags: screen

Before I was able to long-press middle button and get mini-menu with things that was android captured from the screen, including ability to select text directly from images for translation etc.

Now when I long press middle button I get big menu at the bottom with Google assistant, I still can get things captured from the screen if I press "what's on my screen" option, but text recognition from images is gone. I need it back.

I don't know exactly when this option disappeared, sometime in the previous 2 months.

Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It's the new Google Assistant that replaced the old Google Now on Tap. There are few hacks around to remap your middle button back to Now on tap, but all of them will fail eventually as Google starts depreciating the old feature.

One temporary way is to go in Google settings and change your language to something other than US English (Maybe UK, Aus or Ind?)